# AWS Lambda using boto3.client('iot-data') TIMEOUT as of 2021-01-26

Tags: boto3

I have a very simple AWS Lambda function that has been firing every few seconds for 3 months **without fail**

```py
import boto3

shadow_client = boto3.client('iot-data')
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = shadow_client.list_named_shadows_for_thing(thingName='XXXXXX')
    ...
```

As of 2021-01-26T18:53:05.415+00:00 this has started timing out after 3000ms

I'm also getting notifications of SSL errors suddenly.

I see from [the boto3 release history](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/#history) that yesterday (2021-01-26) was when boto3 1.16.60 was released.  Maybe unrelated.  At the same time there's [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=971162&#971162) post of people reporting SSL errors as of 2021-01-26.  They point to AWS maybe switching from one boto3 version to another.

any calls to any boto3.client('iot-data') functions time out after 3000ms:

```py
boto3.client('iot-data').list_named_shadows_for_thing()
boto3.client('iot-data').get_thing_shadow()
```

Can anyone help me:

1. fix it
2. avoid changes to boto3 stopping my code running in the future?

---

Error Logs:

> [ERROR] SSLError: SSL validation failed for
> https://data.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/things/XXXX/shadow [SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
> local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091) Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 37, in
> lambda_handler     client_shadow =
> get_shadow(clientID)['state']['desired']   File
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 94, in get_shadow     response =
> iot_data_client.get_thing_shadow(thingName=thing_name)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call     return
> self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 663, in _make_api_call
> operation_model, request_dict, request_context)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 682, in _make_request
> return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
> File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
> return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
> success_response, exception):   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 256, in _needs_retry
> caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit     return
> self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit     return
> self._emit(event_name, kwargs)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit     response =
> handler(**kwargs)   File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line
> 183, in **call**     if self._checker(attempts, response,
> caught_exception):   File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py",
> line 251, in **call**     caught_exception)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
> return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
> File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in **call**
> caught_exception)   File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line
> 223, in **call**     attempt_number, caught_exception)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in
> _check_caught_exception     raise caught_exception   File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
> http_response = self._send(request)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 269, in _send     return
> self.http_session.send(request)   File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/httpsession.py", line 281, in send     raise
> SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e) @timestamp     1611687531606

Actually the timeouts happen silently and are only visible from the logs by searching for timeout

> ingestionTime
> 1611687185615
> log
> 535942143265:/aws/lambda/XXXXXXXXXXX
> logStream
> 2021/01/26/[$LATEST]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> message
> 2021-01-26T18:53:05.415Z 0b454f65-1366-4525-8288-940d6f667e6c Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
> requestId
> 0b454f65-1366-4525-8288-940d6f667e6c
> timestamp
> 1611687185415

Answer (score 7):

SOLVED.
According to Amazon..

> We are very sorry for this inconvenience. The root cause is likely that newer versions of boto3 import the latest release of an underlying security module, certifi, for certificate validation. In the December release of certifi, they removed trust for the VeriSign root CA that signs the certificate for the default iotdata endpoint used by boto3. The fix is to set the iotdata endpoint to use your customer-specific iot core ATS URL. You can find this by calling "aws iot describe-endpoint --endpoint-type iot:data-ats" in the CLI or from the settings menu in the IoT Core console. We are working to resolve this in future boto3 releases.

[Solution here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=971385#971385)

here's the simple version of the fix

```py
#EDIT THIS LINE TO USE ENDPOINT URL
client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='eu-central-1', endpoint_url='https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')
```

where xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com is your endpoint [from AWS](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iot/home?region=eu-central-%201#/settings)

Comment: this is still failing for unnamed shadows.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [Andrew Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15092926/andrew-smith)'s answer above, you can avoid hardcoding the IoT endpoint in to your code like this:

```
iot_client = boto3.client('iot', region_name=os.environ['AWS_REGION'])
endpoint_response = iot_client.describe_endpoint(endpointType='iot:Data-ATS')
endpoint_url = f"https://{endpoint_response['endpointAddress']}"
client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name=os.environ['AWS_REGION'], endpoint_url=endpoint_url)
```

This assumes that you're running your code in Lambda where the `AWS_REGION` environment variable is automatically set to the AWS region the code is running in; otherwise use `region_name="eu-central-1"` as appropriate for your region.

The code needs to run under a user or role which allows the `iot:DescribeEndpoint` action.