# Unable to publish message to AWS iot core using lambda function. Where lambda is deployed in a VPC

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core

Using lambda function trying to publsh a message to AWS iot core. Where lambda is connected to VPC. Using VPC endpoint I need to publish message to IOT core.

I configured VPC endpoint and created private hosted zone for it
When I tried to publish message. Getting ERROR TIMED OUT

```html
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='xxxx')



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.publish(
        topic='esp32/sub',
        qos=1,
        payload=json.dumps({"foo":"bar"})
    )
    print(response)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Published to topic')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Lambda function needs to reach endpoints on the internet then ensure a default route from the Lambda function's private subnets to a NAT instance or NAT Gateway in a public subnet. And configure an IGW, if needed, without which internet access is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps descrived in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/IoTCore-VPC.html to create an Amazon VPC interface endpoint for IoT Core and Configure a private hosted zone and I managed to publish messages to IoT Core ATS endpoint from a Lambda inside a VPC.

Some suggestions on what to check:

1- Ensure that you are using the ats endpoint as suggested here: [AWS Lambda using boto3.client('iot-data') TIMEOUT as of 2021-01-26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65923558/aws-lambda-using-boto3-clientiot-data-timeout-as-of-2021-01-26).

```
client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='eu-central-1', endpoint_url='https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')
```

You can use this command to retrieve the ats endpoint:

```
aws iot describe-endpoint --endpoint-type iot:Data-ATS
```

2- Check Security groups for Lambda and VPC-endpoint and check inbound/outbound rules.

3- Ensure that VPC Endpoint has the same subnets associated as the Lambda Function.

4- On Route 53 use the general DNS name of the VPC Endpoint vpce-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.data.iot.eu-west-1.vpce.amazonaws.com rather than subnets specific ones: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-eu-west-1b.data.iot.eu-west-1.vpce.amazonaws.com